# Microsoft.Practices.Unity nowhere to be found

Tags: c#

Using Visual Studio 2012 and have no idea why `Microsoft.Practices.Unity` is not under the assembly tab (or any tab for that matter) when I try to add it as a reference.  Working on a C# solution that was originally a Visual Studio 2010 solution on Visual Studio 2012.

Is this namespace deprecated and/or is there another namespace where I can use the `InjectionConstructor` object?

Anyone have any idea why my Microsoft VS 2012 does not have a `Microsoft.Practices.Unity` namespace?

Comment: Go to references, right click and select "Manage Nuget Packages".  Then type Unity in the search.  It'll come right up and install into your project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because it is a standalone project,

https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity

or part of EntLib,

http://entlib.codeplex.com/

but never was part of Visual Studio.

@paqogomez is right that you can simply grab it from NuGet. You can also grab the source code from GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

You can install it to your projects with [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity/3.0.1304.1), directly out of Visual Studio. NuGet is a preinstalled component of Visual Studio since Version 2012.